# Windows Media Player - Missing ID3 tags on some ripped CD tracks

Tags: windows-media-player, metadata, id3

Consider that you have WMP configured to automatically rip CDs when they are inserted.

1. You insert a CD
2. WMP starts ripping it, and also starts looking up the CD metadata online.  During the lookup process the CD tracks are initially stored in an "Unknown Artist/Unknown Album" folder (with date/time stamp added).
3. The metadata lookup completes and the artist/album folders are renamed appropriately and the individual track files are renamed as well.

Note that during the initial processing, several tracks were ripped before album/artist information was available.  While WMP renamed the folders/files correctly, it did not apply ID3 tag information to the track files that were ripped prior to the metadata being retrieved.  If you examine the folder with a tag tool such as mp3tag, you see that the first two or three track files have no ID3 data, while later ones do.

Is it possible to make WMP retrieve metadata again and apply it to the untagged tracks?  I have already tried "Find Album Info" and "Update Album Info", neither of which makes any changes to the ID3 tags.

- O/S Version: Windows 10 Pro X64 1803
- WMP Version: 12.0.17134.799
- Write Media Information Changes to Files: ENABLED

Comment: Which version of WMP on which version of Windows do you use? Is `Write media information changes to files` enabled in WMP's `Options` - `Library`?

Comment: @TimDeBaets I added the requested information to the post.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that WMP is set to rip the tracks to MP3? If you try manually changing one of the tags in the library, such as Title, does it get written to file then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a workaround. However it only works if you have a correct and identical file naming (e.g. track number_artist_title).

1. Download the free software Mp3tag
2. Import the folders with the music (not too many at the time - I used to import around 1000-2000 music tracks per time)
3. Sort all the tracks that are "Unknown" after each other
4. Mark all the tracks with the "Unknown" ID3 Tags holding the shift-key
5. Click on the icon "Filename - Tag" (Dateiname - Tag)
6. Define the rule how the files are named (e.g. track number_artist_title --> %track%*%artist%*%title%)
7. Click "OK" and the ID3 Tags are generated
8. Repeat until you have named all your files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was driving me crazy for a while.  I ripped a bunch of CDs to FLAC format before noticing the missing metadata for (usually) the first track.

I created a Python script to fix the problem quickly.  You need to be a bit tech savvy but it does the job!

Check out https://github.com/joegiglio/FixTracks.  Good luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for the python script!  I used it successfully across hundreds of rips. I touched it up a little (it had issues with some of the files in my 10,000+ track library). I will try to submit my fixes in github (in the coming week or two).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to rip the CD with Windows Media Player and then take the CD out, delete the ripped CD files from your hard drive (or move them) and then reinsert the same CD and rip it a 2nd time and see any missing or unknown track or album properties magically become available (Usually some properties in tracks 1-3 that show as "Unknown" after the first rip but your mileage may differ).

It's likely that this is due to some digital rights management handling limitation of Windows Media Player whereby it requires a bit more time investment to deter the wholesale illegal copying of music CDs.

Answer (score 0):

Also created a python script. Assumes folder path contains artist/album information:

```
#When ripping music CDs with windows media player the metadata may not come through. 
#Install Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/ and run the cmd prompt
#!pip install eyed3
#Use Spyder to write/execute a .py script file

import os
import eyed3

def update_mp3_metadata(folder_path):
    # Iterate through all MP3 files in the specified folder
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(".mp3"):
                mp3_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

                # Extract artist and album from folder path
                artist = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(mp3_path)))
                album = os.path.basename(root)

                # Extract title from filename (excluding track information)
                title = filename[3:-4]  # Assuming track info is 3 characters long

                # Update MP3 metadata
                audiofile = eyed3.load(mp3_path)
                audiofile.tag.artist = artist
                audiofile.tag.album = album
                audiofile.tag.title = title
                audiofile.tag.save()

                print(f"Updated metadata for {filename}:")
                print(f"  Artist: {artist}")
                print(f"  Album: {album}")
                print(f"  Title: {title}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = r"G:\My Drive\Artist\Album" #paste own path here
    update_mp3_metadata(folder_path)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).